# can i draw path on a google earth image?

Tags: google-maps, java-me, google-earth

hi all
i want to ask about using j2me to program path navigation by using google earth map 
i dont found the static map of my country and my city ( iraq - mosul ) so i ask can i take the image from google earth and make a placemarks and draw path between then , i hope i found the answer because i am student researcher to complete my research to get the master
thanks for help me .

hiba

Comment: I tried to answer as fully as possible but I am not 100% sure what you are asking. I am sure I can help though - so if I have not covered it then please give more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in the Google Earth application freely, simply drop the placemarks where you want and draw any linestrings you require.

GE: http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_uk/earth/index.html

You can save this data as a KML file that can be loaded into most GIS applications including Gooogle Earth and Maps. KML is just and XML file so you could always just put it together by hand in a text editor as well...

KML: http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/

Failing that you could use either the Gooogle Maps or Google Earth api to create the data.

Maps: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

Earth: http://code.google.com/apis/earth/

Comment: thanks fraser , i want to program in a j2me , i dont know the way of manuplate the kml file in my program , for example if i save the street from 2 placemark in google earth as kml file how can i reached to the values of longitute and latitiute that saved in kml by my program in j2me ,i hope you can help me

Comment: Like I said, kml is just xml, so just use an xml parser in j2me - http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/parsingxml/ - you could then deserialise the data into objects.